# How can I debug a single Perl unit test sub?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, modulino

I have the usual MakeMaker module with a `t/` tests directory, and I can run a single test file with e.g., `prove -I lib t/my-test.t`.

My tests use `Test::Class` and `Test::More` and subs (with the modulino technique from Effective Perl), like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use base 'Test::Class';  
use Test::More;

__PACKAGE__->runtests() unless caller;

sub set_up : Test(setup) {
    # ...
} 

sub test_something : Test {
    is(MyModule::some_sub(1), 1);
}

# ...more test subs...
```

Now I want to use the Perl debugger to investigate a test sub that shows a problem in my module. I want to only run `test_something` in the debugger, without running all the other test subs in the `.t` file.

`prove` does not seem to have such an option.

`perl -d -I lib t/my-test.t` runs all tests, unless I change my modulino to call the setup method and then the actual test method instead of `__PACKAGE__->runtests()`:

```
unless (caller) { 
    set_up(); 
    test_something();  
    done_testing();  
}
```

How can I run only one test sub without modifying the code?

Comment: You can't run just part of a program, test script or otherwise.

Comment: @ikegami I kind of can by calling just the sub I want, but I am looking for a way to do that without modifying my test.

Comment: Your program runs all tests, and you can't run just part of a program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To avoid running all of your tests, `caller` must be defined when your test script is loaded. Try something like this:

```
$ perl -Ilib -de 1
DB<1>   do 't/my-test.t'
DB<2>   set_up()
DB<3>   b test_something_else
DB<4>   test_something_else()
    ... step through test_something_else() function ...
DB<16>   done_testing()
```